# How to read values from a DataGridView.Rows collection and assign them to a list of custom objects?

Tags: c#, list, object, datagridview, custom-object

My custom object has two properties: `userid` and `username`.
Here I found how to traverse through each `DataGridViewRow` using a `foreach` loop, but I don't get how to assign current cell value to my custom object value.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows) 
{
    ClsOBJ userobj1 = new ClsOBJ();

    foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells) 
    {
        // userobj1.userid =
        // cell index 0 should be read to userid
        // and cell index 1 should be read to username
        // userobj1.username =
    }

    list1.Add(userobj1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to iterate through the collection of cells. Just access each one and convert it as needed:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows) 
{
    ClsOBJ userobj1 = new ClsOBJ();

    userobj1.userid = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells[0].Value);
    userobj1.username = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells[1]);

    list1.Add(userobj1);
}
```

You could populate the list using [LINQ](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b), but if you're unfamiliar with it, the `foreach` loop is perfectly fine.

```
list1.AddRange(
    dataGridView1.Rows
                 .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                 .Select(x => new ClsOBJ
                                  {
                                    userid = Convert.ToInt32(x.Cells[0].Value),
                                    username = Convert.ToString(x.Cells[1].Value)
                                  }));
```